# Is it possible to make a TreeView node edit objects within the form?

Tags: vb.net, treeview

'Talking about my findings and failure to discover what I wanted

Delving deeper into Windows Form, in which I've been using for a little over half a year, I began to use newer objects such as Tree View. This became an obstacle in my project, impeding further progress by hours due to the lack of knowledge of this particular object. So far, I've seen countless discussions and videos of creating nodes for Tree View and whatnot, but still have not found what I was looking for.

'Is this possible?

I want to use Tree View as something similar to a list box, which I used instead of List View because it's basically the simplest list in Windows Forms (currently learning more about list view and tree view objects). This time, I used Tree View in place of list box to have it change labels, add images, videos, and other objects (as such, I have done so by using list box, but tree view fits what I had in mind a lot better and would also save me hundreds of lines of code - figured after I had replaced the list box and the code along with it - as to why, because it was a list within a list which is pretty much a tree view in that aspect).

'What I planned on doing

If my tree view has a parent node, let's say 'Numbers,' then
inside of Numbers consists of children called '1, 2, and 3.'

When child node, 1, is selected/clicked on, then label will display "Numbers - 1" (shows directory/path of list) and invisible objects will then be visible. 
- Likewise, if 2 is selected, the label will display "Numbers - 2" and other objects will change as a result of the click event.

'What I have created (still an example, no code, just TreeView object and its nodes)

'Conclusion

If you have tried this before or know how to do this, please let me know. Furthermore, if you attempt this, please show me what you have tried, thanks!

---

Some things I tried

- Looking for any possible methods to enable this
- Contain method. If SelectedNode = "1" Then change Label.Text

---

Haven't tried

- Would element selection work?

p = parent
c = child
(p, c)
(0, 1) - Like an array, 0 would be the first element, and 1 would be child node 2.

- CheckBox (property in TreeView that makes Tree View nodes have checkboxes next to them), something I didn't want, but may end up using if necessary

Comment: You need to start thinking in terms of events. You want something to happen when you perform a particular action in the UI. You need to determine what event is raised when you do that and handle it. The event handler is where you put the code that you want executed when the event is raised. Start by reading the documentation for the `TreeView` to see what events it has and which one is raised when you want to act.

Comment: Once you have the event handler in place, you can then look at how to get the appropriate node. That will either be done via the data passed to the handler or via the `TreeView` itself. Check the former first and, if there's nothing useful, read the documentation for the `TreeView` to see what properties and methods it has and which one(s) expose the data you need.

Comment: Once you have the node, you can then look at the actual values you want to display. Again, documentation, properties, methods.

Comment: Don't put resolved in the title or question.  Accepting an answer is good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can make a TreeView node control properties of other objects.

Making TreeView node change text of a label:

```
TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = Label1.Text
```

Likewise, you can control other events when a node is selected, by:

```
If TreeView1.SelectedNode.Text = "Colors" Then
   Label1.Text = "Colors: Red, Green, Blue"
   PictureBox1.Image = My.Resources.RGB ' Shows image of primary colors: Red, Green, Blue
End If
```

Pretty much what I wanted... Spent probably 6 hours looking for how to implement this into my program. It would've taken at least 5 minutes to look for this.
Anyways, hope this helps someone!